# is right to implement a business logic in the type binding DI framwork?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

```
public IRedirect FactoryStrategyRedirect()
{
  if (_PasswordExpired) {
    return _UpdatePasswordRedirectorFactory.Create();
  } else {
    return _DefaultRedirectorFactory.Create();
  }
}
```

This strategy factory method can be replaced with type binding and when clause:

```
Bind<IRedirect>.To<UpdatePasswordRedirector>.When(c=> c.kernel.get<SomeContext>().PasswordExpired()) 
Bind<IRedirect>.To<DefaultRedirector>.When(c=> not c.kernel.get<SomeContext>().PasswordExpired())
```

I wonder which of the two approaches is the more correct. What are the pros and cons.

Especially in the case in which the logic is more complex with more variables to test and more concrete classes to return.

is right to implement a business logic in the binding?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in any case you should prevent having business logic inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). You composition root should all about wiring things correctly and you want to have integration tests that test the correctness of this wiring.

The application code should be all about business logic and you should have unit tests that verify the business logic.

Although in your case the difference would probably be insignificant, the line starts to blur rather quickly, and you'll end up with a Composition Root that will be complex, hard to read and hard to maintain.

Comment: I fully agree.

One might add, as a beacon, that when the "composition Root" is dynamic then it would be good to implement it with a classic AbstractFactory as in the example above?

Comment: What do you mean by an dynamic composition root? Note that the abstract factory pattern is still a very valid pattern when applying Dependency Injection.

Comment: I'm sorry, but perhaps the more correct termin is "dynamic object graph." I mean the presence of more than one object graph for the same root object at run-time. The "discriminatory" for the selection of the object praph dependent on the context at run-time and not by configuration variables.

Comment: But perhaps, there is no overlap between business logic and dynamism: Not everything that is dynamic is also business logic.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Every object graph has some dynamic parts, since there's almost always a need for factories.